# How to add and sync Gsuite calender in calender?

Tags: release-hera

I am new to Elementary OS and I understand there is no integration of google account like there is in Gnome but there is an option to add google calendar. I am looking to add my Gsuite account's calendar. may I know how to do it? is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

-When you open Calendar, there's a cog on the top right of the window which will open up an options dropdown.

-From there you can add a new calendar by clicking the "Add New Calendar..." option.

-Then, you would open the "Type" dropdown and select "Google". You would then name your calendar, and enter the Gmail address associated with the specific GSuite calendar you're attempting to sync and then choose "Create Calendar". Separate addresses might appear in your GSuite dashboard. You might also have GSuite calendars nested under the main Gmail address.

-Afterwards, you will be prompted for the password to authenticate the calendar add.

*Please note that if you use 2FA (Two Factor Authentication), you will need to create an app password specifically for this at https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords and enter that instead of your normal password.*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you don't get my question. the method you say works for gmail but not for gsuite users.